# How to structure a multi-parameter search in Falcor

Tags: falcor

What are the best practices in constructing search paths for Falcor queries?

Here an example from a Staffing domain where a staffing coordinator is trying to staff people for project needs:

- A need has `startDate` and an `endDate` - both are simple string properties of the need
- A need is for a `project`, hence it has a reference to a project
- A need is for a `skill`, so it has a reference to a skill

Here's what a need looks like in a needMap:

```
needMap: {
    101: {
        startDate: '2016-07-04T04:00:00.000Z',
        endDate: '2016-10-22T03:59:59.999Z',
        project: $ref('projectMap[87]'),
        skill: $ref('skillMap[3]')
    },
    ...
}
```

How do I specify a search for all needs that match the following criteria:

- `minStartDate`: minimum start date for the need
- `maxStartDate`: maximum start date for the need
- `projectId`: filter to needs to only this project
- `skillId`: filter to needs to only this skill

Note: I am not looking for the code or ideas to do the actual search, only how to specify the search using Falcor path concepts.

Answer (score 2):

The issues [#713](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/713) and [#775](https://github.com/Netflix/falcor/issues/775) from the falcor repository in github address this. Two possible solutions appear :

- You can use a query string, for your case it would be something like this : `model.get(["needs", "search", "minStartDate=2016&maxStartDate=2016&projectId=$ref(projectMap[87])])`
- You can use another endpoint for the search, and then use falcor only to get more info about the result the other endpoint returned

I guess another option would be to use a `call` rather than a `get`, as this allow you to pass multiple parameters. You would have something like this:

```
model.call(
    ["model", "search"],
    {
        minStartDate: "2016",
        maxStartDate: "2016",
        projectId: $ref('projectMap[87])
    },
    [],
    []);
```