# Netflix Falcor: Filters in model's get operation

Tags: javascript, falcor

We are trying to integrate [Netflix's Falcor](https://netflix.github.io/falcor/) into our system. 
How could we retrieve paths based on a filter. For example, if we would like to get Todos that have a `done: false` value.

JSON Graph Example:

```
{
    todosById: {
        "44": {
            name: "Login to stackoverflow",
            done: true,
            prerequisites: []
        },
        "54": {
            name: "Ask question on stackoverflow",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: [{ $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }]
        },            
        "64": {
            name: "Accept answer",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: []
        }
    },
    todos: [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 44] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 64] }
    ]
}
```

Now we want to get only todos which aren't `done: true` yet.

Getting all todos and filtering on client side seems redundant. I am presuming we might need to use the `call` operation, but I couldn't find any example on how to implement a function in a JSON graph in the guides. (Also not sure if there might be a better way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of your model as containing everything the client can ask for, and not as only stored data. This is what you want:

```
{
    todosByDone: {
        "true": [
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 44] }
        ],
        "false": [
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] },
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 64] }
        ]
    },
    todosById: {
        "44": {
            name: "Login to stackoverflow",
            done: true,
            prerequisites: []
        },
        "54": {
            name: "Ask question on stackoverflow",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: [{ $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] }]
        },            
        "64": {
            name: "Accept answer",
            done: false,
            prerequisites: []
        }
    },
    todos: [
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 44] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 54] },
        { $type: "ref", value: ["todosById", 64] }
    ]
}
```

And then you can request done todos like any other array: `todosByDone.true[0..10]`. Of course you can design your model as you want, and there lots of possibilities. Consider modeling from the point of view of the client. For example, it would be nice if the client could do `todos.done` and `todos.todo` (aka not done). Then your model would look something like:

```
{
    todos: {
        done: [
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 44] }
        ],
        todo: [
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 54] },
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 64] }
        ],
        byId: {
            "44": {
                name: "Login to stackoverflow",
                done: true,
                prerequisites: []
            },
            "54": {
                name: "Ask question on stackoverflow",
                done: false,
                prerequisites: [{ $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 54] }]
            },            
            "64": {
                name: "Accept answer",
                done: false,
                prerequisites: []
            }
        },
        byCreationTime: [
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 44] },
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 54] },
            { $type: "ref", value: ["todos", "byId", 64] }
        ]
    },

}
```

Feel free to explore [this app](https://github.com/hgwood/falcorception) for some examples.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your solution does solve the problem I posted in the question, and therefore I have accepted it. But in a case where you might have 10 different statuses, and you might want to show different combination of them all, where I want to be able to view any number of statuses together (for example, just "done", or "done, pending, deferred" etc.), building a model to contain all of the combinations seems to be too much.

Comment: @omerts [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37441128/how-to-structure-a-multi-parameter-search-in-falcor) is about that case.